# UIView animation recall will move quickly

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a `UIButton`, when I click the button, it will call animation method. But when I click again, the animation will become strange, it will move quickly. How do I rebuild the animation when I click button? Thanks.

I have try `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]`, but not working.

This is my button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   ...
   [_go_button addTarget:self action:@selector(animation_go:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ...
}
```

This is `animation_go:` method

```
- (void)animation_go:(id)sender
{
   ...
   for (int start = 0; start < end; start++) {
      // that will create four uiview and add to self.view
   }
   _thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animation) object:nil];
   [_thread start];
}
```

This is `animation` method

```
- (void)animation
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Move randomly" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.06];

    CGPoint squarePostion1 = [self return_point:_first_view add_view:_add_first_view tag:1];
    _add_first_view.center = squarePostion1;

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animation)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: did you mean [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations] ?

Comment: It is my fault, thank you.

Comment: Please, clarify what kind of effect you want to achieve? By clicking button while animation is on animation should stop and begin from the initial state? And it is just simple translation animation?

Comment: Yes. I want animation become initial state.

Comment: Thank you~!! Your example of great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CABasicAnimation instead:

```
CABasicAnimation* translationAnimation;
translationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
translationAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(266, 266)];
translationAnimation.duration = 1;
translationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
translationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
translationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
translationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.label.layer addAnimation:translationAnimation forKey:@"positionAnimation"];
```

This code provides you basic, single-keyframe animation capabilities for a layer property. You also can implement pause/start layer animation feature according Apple's technical note [QA1673](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html).

[Check out my github sample code.](https://github.com/gneil90/pause-layer-animation)